# Debian 7.11 - How to capture SMPP all arrived and sent packets by some ports

Tags: tcp, wireshark, tcpdump, smpp, packets

I'm using following code for capturing incoming and outgoing tcp packets by ports:

```
tcpdump -i any -s 0 -vvv -A port 3727 or port 5016 or port 3724 -w /home/admin/dump1.cap
```

But tcpdump captures only incoming packets, I need incoming and outgoing packets at the same time. Anybody know where my mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your command should work. Have you tried only capturing outgoing packets to test if there are any outgoing packets on these ports?

Comment: @Lukas yes work but just for incoming packets. But not exists outgoing packets. I can capture outgoing packets, but can't capture incoming and together thereof in the same time with same line command why?

Comment: this is my capture outgoing packets command: tcpdump -s0 -vvv -A -n src host 80.81.110.111 -w /home/admin/aaa_tmp/dump3.cap : this command works just for outgoing packets

Comment: tcpdump -i eth1 -vvv -s 0 -w /home/sunetadmin/aaa_tmp/dmp7.pcap - this command works to both packets, but here i can't add ports, if i will add ports  it is works only for incoming packets

Comment: I need tcpdump command by ports for capturing incoming and outgoing packets in the same time

Comment: The command should work fine. You must update your question with the following details:

1. What trafic (TCP, UDP, application layer protocols) are you trying to capture?

2. How do you read your results? What command/script? Show details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen if your traffic is going through an ipsec tunnel (check whether this is the case by running `ipsec statusall`). To capture decrypted packets you can add IPtables rules to forward ipsec traffic to the nflog interface:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -m policy --pol ipsec --dir in -j NFLOG --nflog-group 5
iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j NFLOG --nflog-group 5
```

Then tcpdump the nflog interface:

```
tcpdump -i nflog:5 -y IPV4 -s0 -A port 3727 or port 5016 or port 3724
```

Remember to remove the nflog rules when you're done!

```
iptables -t mangle -D PREROUTING -m policy --pol ipsec --dir in -j NFLOG --nflog-group 5
iptables -t mangle -D POSTROUTING -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j NFLOG --nflog-group 5
```

Source: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/CorrectTrafficDump

Answer (score 6):

```
tcpdump -i any -s 0 -vvv -A port 3727 or port 5016 or port 3724 --direction=in --direction=out -w /home/admin/dump1.cap
```

--direction=in for the incoming traffic
--direction=out for the outgoing traffic.

More you can find on the manual page of tcpdump.
http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html

Comment: hi, thank you for answer, tried your answer but not works 0 packets did capture.

Comment: @mr.boyfox, in my computer it captures, probably, you should find your firewall settings or something. I ran via root.

Comment: Maybe, i did run with root, too. Because, just a root can start tcpdump in our server, i will searching firewall settings and other problems related to tcpdump